# Strange behavior with --code and -F options when giving path argument (Windows)

Tags: qgis, windows

I try to run a Python code at QGIS startup. To run a code from file, you need the --code option. To add an argument to the python program, you can use the -F option.

However, when using -F option with Windows path, there is a strange behavior. The only way to give a path as argument is to use `/` or `\\\\`. Usually, you just need a double backslashes.

It's annoying because I can't use Path lib with the -F option while pathlib is suppose to solve this kind of problem.

The code is:

```py
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

qgis_exe = shutil.which("qgis")

path_to_code = "C:\\Users\\$USER\\homec\\open_qgis.py" # It works
# path_to_code = "C:/Users/$USER/homec/open_qgis.py" # It works too
# path_to_code = Path("C:/Users/$USER/homec/open_qgis.py") # It works too
# path_to_code = "C:\\Users\\$USER\\homec\\open_qgis.py" # It does not work and that's normal

first_argument = "C:\\Users\\$USER\\homec\\open_qgis.py"  # It does not work
# first_argument = Path("C:\\Users\\$USER\\homec\\open_qgis.py")  # It does not work
# first_argument = "C:/Users/$USER/homec/open_qgis.py" # It works
# first_argument = "C:\\\\Users\\\\$USER\\\\homec\\\\open_qgis.py" # It works
cmd_list = [
    qgis_exe, 
    "--code", 
    path_to_code, 
    "-F", 
    first_argument
]

subprocess.run(cmd_list, capture_output=True, shell=False)
```

open_qgis.py

```
import sys
python_file = sys.argv[1]
from pathlib import Path
print(f"Run python file {python_file}")
```

The error is :

> Une erreur est survenue lors de l'exécution du code suivant: sys.argv
> = ['C:/Users/$USER/homec/open_qgis.py','C:\Users\bcoriat$USER\open_qgis.py']
>
> File "", line 1
> sys.argv = ['C:/Users/$USER/homec/open_qgis.py','C:\Users\bcoriat$USER\open_qgis.py']
> ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode
> bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

The error occurs here in QGis:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d5b9669dd0dad2536606ddbe1585aa01d7e24318/src/app/main.cpp#L1648

Similarly, in the Windows command prompt, the following works :

```
qgis.bat --code C:\Users\$USER\homec\open_qgis.py -F C:\\Users\\$USER\\homec\\open_qgis.py
```

But not this one :

```
qgis.bat --code C:\Users\$USER\homec\open_qgis.py -F C:\Users\$USER\homec\open_qgis.pys
```

It's just like QGIS does not interpret the right encoding or edit the args before actually giving them to Python.

I think it's a bug or a not expected behavior.

Any idea?